# Is it an anti-pattern to build a REST API powered by ElasticSearch?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

For example, if I want to build a series of Lambda micro-services which hit an ElasticSearch instance, is this an anti-pattern? I saw that there was a project a while back called Ramses, but is not supported anymore, so I am wondering if there's a better way to achieve these results that I'm simply not aware of.

I know that ElasticSearch has its own REST API as well, but I want to tailor the interface to our data and provide a more limited but concise request syntax.

Comment: I don't think so, why would it be? APIs should be independent of their internal implementation, as long as it does what it promises, it can be done in any way. Be it call an ElasticSearch server, calculate it all by itself, call a database, call another webservice, whatever it needs. The last paragraph hints that you're building a sort of adapter frontend to ElasticSearch, I don't find anything bad with it.

Comment: To be quite honest, the only reason it worried me was because A) there was very little evidence of people doing this when I was Googling it, and B) it seemed like an unnecessary relay on top of an existing API. But now I don't feel as crazy. :)
Thanks.